# Add VM to Existing Lab

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, microsoft-test-manager, lab-management

Good morning.  This may be a very novice question and/or a lack of understanding surrounding TFS and Microsoft Test Manager.  Nonetheless, I would very much appreciate some guidance from the community.

The situation is very simple.  I have existing labs that have been created using Microsoft Test Manager in conjunction with System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2012 SP1 on the backend.  There is a need to add a new virtual server to the existing labs.  Between SCVMM and Microsoft Test Manager, I cannot find any way to accomplish this, nor can I find any documentation in TechNet or MSDN that explains how this can be accomplished.

If anyone has done this successfully, or if anyone has information pertaining to how this can be accomplished the assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add new VM to a **stored** environment only.
That means you should **in MTM**:

- Shut down your environment
- Select "Store in the library" from menu or context menu.
  You can select location (the library to store into) on SCVMM machine then.
- Go to the *Library* tab in *MTM / Lab Center*
- Open environment you have just stored

Now you will be able to add further VMs to it.
After that you can just deploy changed environment.

But be aware: if you add/remove VMs to/from existing environment ***you will lose all existing snapshots*** of this environment.
So if you have some important snapshots you will have to consider how to deal with them before storing the environment.

PS: It's a pity it is not described nowhere neither in TechNet nor in MSDN... I found it out by chance...

Comment: Thanks Elena, I will give this a shot.  Do you know if I can add load balancing to a lab in the same manner?

Comment: What do you mean with "load balancing" exactly? Do you want to distribute running test among several VMs belonging to the same environment? (PS: I've just slightly improved my answer in order to make clear that you should perform all actions in MTM, including storing environment in the library.)

Comment: The load balancing that I am talking about is native to SCVMM.  I am using network isolated labs, deployed via MTM as you have suggested.  Load balancing is available through SCVMM, but there does not appear to be any means of configuration using MTM for that.

Comment: I don't think MTM support load balancing provided by SCVMM. But since I've never needed it for my test labs so far it could be I'm just not aware of it... What about a new question on SO?